# Missing Composite C1 CMS Packages option

Tags: package, c1-cms

Picked up an existing project built on Composite C1 version 4.3, and I'm trying to install a package. All the information online says to go to System -> Packages -> Install Local Package, but I don't even see a Packages option on the System page at all.

I've tried to see if this option was disabled or not available in this version, but nothing definitive so far.

[image]

EDIT:
I do have direct access to code, so if there's a config file I could edit it directly, but haven't found anything that indicates where this might be.

Comment: In addition I seem to be missing the Data Navigation item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two files I needed to change were **IUserActivePerspective**, and **IUserGroupActivePerspective**. The perspectives for what I was missing were removed from the admin account, so I just needed to add them back there.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the account that you are logging in with isn't the main admin account. It's probably a developer account to which the admin has added the ability to make backups and tweak Google Analytics settings. You'll need to contact the admin and ask them to give you full privileges, in order to install packages yourself.

If you have FTP access to the website, there is a way to move an account from one group to another:

Open: ~/App_Data/Composite/DataStores/Composite.Data.Types.IUser.xml

Find the user account for the user you want to change group membership for, and make a note of the Id GUID value.

Open: ~/App_Data/Composite/DataStores/Composite.Data.Types.IUserGroup.xml

Find the group you want that account to have membership of (ie: Administrator or Admin), and make a note of the Id GUID value.

Open: ~/App_Data/Composite/DataStores/Composite.Data.Types.IUserUserGroupRelation.xml

Make a backup copy of this file, just in case it doesn't work!

In the origional, find UserId GUID matching your account Id, then ammend the UserGroupId to the group Id. Save the file.

I've tried this out on my local copy of C1 and it appears to work. You should now have access to everything the admin has access to.

Comment: Yea I had the same thought and I'm trying to get the information from the client, but it seems like the old dev is gone and they didn't have the foresight to get this info from them. I do have direct access to the code itself. Is there an xml file or something I could edit directly to give myself these permissions? I've been trying to find something like this, but with no luck so far.

Comment: As you have file access, I've edited my answer with a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks! In those files the group relation is already set; however, you pointing these files out did help me find the files I actually needed to changes.

Answer (score 0):

i downloaded the old version of C1 4.3 from github and started a new site, and looks like something is wrong with your site, because this version have package manager.

Something error on Log's Folder? (no Console Log item found in your capture)

I tested on this version (see the image uploaded), so, wich especific version have you?

[image: Version Installed for Testing]

Comment: That's the version I have as well. Are you logged in as the admin?